# kubectl error: "You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)"

Tags: kubernetes

I'm running the following command and getting an error:

```
$ kubectl get nodes
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
```

What's going on?

Comment: Did you figure out an answer for this? I am facing the similar error after configuring oidc with k8s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to run:

```
$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials [cluster-name]
```

Docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials?hl=en_US&_ga=1.254512651.2069297816.1484122139).

Answer (score 0):

$gcloud config set compute/zone [zone]

$gcloud container clusters get-credentials [clustername]

Answer (score 0):

Re-setting the compute/zone seems to do the trick. 
Using this command

```
gcloud container clusters list
```

I got

```
NAME  ZONE            MASTER_VERSION  MASTER_IP      MACHINE_TYPE   NODE_VERSION  NUM_NODES  STATUS
k0    europe-west1-d  1.6.4           35.187.164.84  n1-standard-1  1.6.4         3          RUNNING
```

So the zone seemed to configured, but it was only after re-executing

```
gcloud config set compute/zone europe-west1-d
```

did things start working again.

So the real question is: why has is the compute zone config suddenly no longer valid?

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar issue in Minikube environment.I restarted minikube and it was working as expected. So if the issue is occurring in Minikube environment Please restart it