# error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am getting this error while running the command "kubectl cluster-info"
I am trying this on a google instance and have installed gcloud sdk as well as kubectl on my instance.
I have tried running this command I found in a solution earlier:-
"sudo sed -i -e 's/true/false/' /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/config.json" and "gcloud container clusters get-credentials [cluster-name]" still no luck.

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [kubectl error: "You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111366/kubectl-error-you-must-be-logged-in-to-the-server-the-server-has-asked-for-th)